# Where can I get some proxy list good for use it with Python?

Tags: python, proxy

Where?

I'm trying google and any of the proxys I've tried worked...

I'm trying urllib.open with it...

I don't know if urllib need some special proxy type or something like that...

Thank you

ps: I need some proxies to ping a certain website and not got banned from my ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up your own proxy and connecting to it...

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't even *need* to use a proxy. The `urllib` module knows how to contact web servers directly.

You may need to use a proxy if you're behind certain kinds of corporate firewalls, but in that case you can't just choose any proxy to use, you have to use the corporate proxy. In such a case, a list of open proxies on Google isn't going to help you.

Comment: I've edited so you can understand better

Comment: Ok, I understand. I have voted to close this question as off-topic, since it is not related to programming.